# How to get swatch image of multiple select attribute values in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, swatches

I am using Magento 2.2.2

I have an attribute called "Brand" and input type for this attribute is multiple select. In this attribute, I have set "Small Image" in additional settings for one of the values. Please refer below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

I have set the value "Test1" in one of the products. so, I want to display a small image(see second screenshot) of this attribute value in listing page. So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have anyone found out the solution for this?

Comment: Also looking for the answer to this question.